# Mysql recursive query - give some results in wrong column

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have mysql table

```
    region_id | name | parent_id
    1 | Österreich   | 0
    3 | Deutschland  | 0
    4 | Bayern       | 3
    5 | Bad Griesbach| 4
    6 | Nordrhein-Westfalen| 3
    7  | Île-de-France | 7
    ....
```

I write the query

```
        SELECT 

                h.hotel_id,
                h.hotel_name,
                t1.region_id,
                t1.name AS name1,
                t2.region_id,
                t2.name AS name2,
                t3.region_id,
                t3.name AS name3

            FROM
                hotel_service.hotel h
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t1 ON t1.region_id = h.region_id
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t2 ON t2.region_id = t1.parent_id
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t3 ON t3.region_id = t2.parent_id

            WHERE
                hotel_id IN ('10640' , '10003', '10004', '10005', '10007')
```

and result like this

```
hotel_id hotel_name city_id name1   region_id   name2 region_id name3   
    10003   Dorfhotel    231    Sylt    30   Schleswig    3   Deutschland               
    10004   Iberotel    22  Boltenhagen 21  Mecklenburg   3   Deutschland               
    10005    Hotel  170    Barcelona   169  Katalonien   168    Spanien             
    10007   Schlosshotel 175 Rügen  21  Mecklenburg       3   Deutschland               
    10640   Hotel Berlin  36    Berlin  3   Deutschland
```

but the problem in order of result for example `hotel_id 10640 -  3 Deutschland` shows in wrong column, its should show on last column because last column is for `country`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: 1- the query don't match the result you have shown as in the result you have city_id not present into the query 2- this behaviour can have 2 causes or wrong parent mapping or t2.parent_id is null and you have a "smaller" row

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for reply, I already saw that post. but i have problem with some hotel result orders. country should come on name3 column...

Comment: @TheOni Thank you for reply, I don't think show i have mapping problem because its perfectly work with almost all hotels but  have a problem with few hotels..

Comment: What is parent_id of region_id = 36 in your table?

Comment: @SerifEmek parent_id of region_id = 36 is 3

Comment: Then there is no problem.

Comment: @SerifEmek I have problem with order arrangement, for this hotel country come into second column instead of third column.. column 2 should be empty for this hotel

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only problematic case you may try this;

```
SELECT 

                h.hotel_id,
                h.hotel_name,
                t1.region_id,
                t1.name AS name1,
case when t3.region_id is null then null else t2.region_id end,   
case when t3.region_id is null then null else t2.name end,      
case when t3.region_id is null then t2.region_id else t3.region_id end,   
case when t3.region_id is null then t2.name else t3.name end
            FROM
                hotel_service.hotel h
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t1 ON t1.region_id = h.region_id
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t2 ON t2.region_id = t1.parent_id
                LEFT JOIN region_service.region t3 ON t3.region_id = t2.parent_id

            WHERE
                hotel_id IN ('10640' , '10003', '10004', '10005', '10007')
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes this one is work. I have one question there is way to solve this issue without using case.

Comment: Because it is not possible to distinguish if a row is a country, a city or a state on the region table, I think you should use something like case, nvl.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply

Comment: You are wellcome.